# Finding code tab's associated schema in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a single-tenant setup of MySQL databases; i.e. a more or less identical schema instance for each client.

When I'm tasked with modifying the code of stored routines, I use MySQL Workbench. After some time I usually find myself having code tabs with similar or identical code for several distinct database schemas.

How do I know to what schema a certain stored routine tab belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's no schema associated with a certain code tab. All tabs use the active schema. There's already a feature request for a schema-per-tab feature.

Update: you meant object editors and indeed there's no indication to which schema they belong. Please file a feature request to get this into MySQL Workbench (http://bugs.mysql.com).

Comment: Not sure I understand. I just tested again. If I pull up two tabs from different schemas, modify the routine code and click Apply, they will try to modify their respective database of origin.

Comment: I was only refering to code editors, not object editors or result sets. The latter 2 have their own storage of the associated schema.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no straightforward way of checking from what schema a code tab originated in MySQL Workbench and this leads to confusion.

One workaround I've found is to make some code change (which you later will have to undo), so that you can click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button. Then you will be presented with a code preview window. In that preview, you will see the schema's name in the top `DROP PROCEDURE` statement. Click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and undo your code changes.